# Datamapper - best practices for pre-loading data

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm writing a web app using Ruby/Sinatra and Datamapper. I have some tables that I want to preload data into. Is there a best practice for that? E.g. I have a table called `references`

```
id name url
-- ---- -------------------
 1 AOL  http://www.aol.com
 2 Dell http://www.dell.com
```

I want to ensure that this data is always loaded when someone starts up the app for the first time *and* and ensure the IDs do not changes....

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a gem out there to do this for you which I'm not aware of, and if there is, I'd love to hear about it.  But, for my last project I simply had my import data in a yaml file and wrote a Ruby class that parsed that yaml file and used DataMapper to insert the data for me.

I then created a Rake task that allowed me to run this Ruby class.

Is this the sort of solution you might be after?  If so, I can give you more info on it.